# Django Template Email

Tags: django, email, template

DJANGO: Alguém poderia me ajudar a colocar template de email (puxar algum html ou css para o conteúdo do email) pela views.py? tentei de tudo quanto é jeito mas não funcionou, grato desde já.

Views.py:

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings

from django.core.mail import send_mail

from .forms import contactForm # Importando classe do forms.py

## Create your views here.

def contact(request):
    title = 'Contato'
    form = contactForm(request.POST or None)
    confirm_message = None

```
if form.is_valid():
    comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    subject = 'Mensagem vinda de MEUSITE.com'
    message = ' %s %s' %(comment, name)
    emailFrom = form.cleaned_data['email']
    emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
    send_mail(subject, message, emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=True)
    title = "Nós agradecemos!!"
    confirm_message = "Obrigado pela mensagem!"
    form = None

context = { 'title': title, 'form': form, 'confirm_message': confirm_message}
template = 'contact.html'
return render(request, template, context)
```

Forms.py:

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms

class contactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Nome:', required = False, max_length = 100, help_text = 'máx. 100 caracteres')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email:', required = True)
    comment = forms.CharField(label='Comentário:', required = True, widget=forms.Textarea)

Answer (score 2):

Opa, espero que isso ajude:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.template import Context
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

...

content = get_template('template_email.html').render(Context({'meu_objeto': meu_objeto}))

email = EmailMessage('titulo', mark_safe(content) ,'remetente@remetente.com', to=['destinatario@destinatario.com'])
email.content_subtype = 'html'
email.send()
```

No seu html, basta chamar seus arquivos de css pelo domínio completo.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/static/css/meucss.css">
```

Quando for jogar para produção, você deve chamar pelo domínio da aplicação:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.meusite.com.br/static/css/meucss.css">
```

Ou enviar o http_host pelo contexto e chamar ele:

```
content = get_template('template_email.html').render(Context({'host': request.META['HTTP_HOST']}))
```

E no template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://{{host}}/static/css/meucss.css">
```

Espero que ajude.